# memcpy error segmentation fault while trying to copy 2D array of 4 char structure in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, memcpy

Hey I'm trying to copy an array of SDL_Color created from an image in another one. But for some images, I get :

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

It happens for an image of 20 x 20 pixels but it works well for a 50 x 50 one...
here is my code :

```
FILE *debugFile = fopen("C:\\Users\\Clement\\Documents\\coding\\ImageOfCLife\\debug.txt", "w+");
int imgWidth, imgHeight, channels;
unsigned char *img = stbi_load("C:\\Users\\Clement\\Documents\\coding\\ImageOfCLife\\star.jpg", &imgWidth,
                               &imgHeight, &channels, 0);
fprintf(debugFile, "Loaded image with a width of %dpx, a imgHeight of %dpx and %d channels\n", imgWidth, imgHeight, channels);
dRulesLen = sizeof(deathRules);
bRulesLen = sizeof(birthRules);
if (img == NULL) {
    fprintf(debugFile, "Error in loading the image\n");
    exit(3);
}

int ch, pix;
SDL_Color **stateMatrix1 = (SDL_Color **) malloc(imgHeight * sizeof(SDL_Color*));
if (stateMatrix1 == NULL) {
    fprintf(debugFile,"Unable to allocate memory\n");
    exit(1);
}
for (int i = 0; i < imgHeight; ++i) {
    stateMatrix1[i] = (SDL_Color *) malloc(imgWidth * sizeof(SDL_Color));
}
for (ch = 0; ch < imgHeight; ch++) {
    printf("{");
    for (pix = 0; pix < imgWidth; pix++) {
        unsigned bytePerSDL_Color = channels;
        unsigned char *SDL_ColorOffset = img + (pix + imgHeight * ch) * bytePerSDL_Color;
        SDL_Color p = initSDL_Color(SDL_ColorOffset);
        stateMatrix1[ch][pix] = p;
        printSDL_Color(p);
        printf(", ");
    }
    printf("}\n");
}
SDL_Color stateMatrix2[imgHeight][imgWidth];
memcpy(stateMatrix2, stateMatrix1, imgWidth*imgHeight*sizeof(SDL_Color));
```

the last line is the problem according to [the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPZdw.png)
I tried

> memcpy(stateMatrix2, stateMatrix1, sizeof(stateMatrix2))

too but I get the same result.

I work on windows 10 with minGW and Clion. I hope you can help me with this issue.

I also tried to replace `SDL_Color stateMatrix2[imgHeight][imgWidth];` by :

```
    SDL_Color **stateMatrix2 = (SDL_Color **) malloc(imgHeight * sizeof(SDL_Color*));
if (stateMatrix2 == NULL) {
    fprintf(debugFile,"Unable to allocate memory\n");
    exit(1);
}
for (int i = 0; i < imgHeight; ++i) {
    stateMatrix2[i] = (SDL_Color *) malloc(imgWidth * sizeof(SDL_Color));
}
```

but i got the same issue.

I forgot to say it but I want ant to be able to use both stateMatrix as parameter of a function.

To fix it I used the Olaf solution explained below :
I kept :

```
SDL_Color **stateMatrix1 = (SDL_Color **) malloc(imgHeight * sizeof(SDL_Color*));
if (stateMatrix1 == NULL) {
    fprintf(debugFile,"Unable to allocate memory\n");
    exit(1);
}
for (int i = 0; i < imgHeight; ++i) {
    stateMatrix1[i] = (SDL_Color *) malloc(imgWidth * sizeof(SDL_Color));
}
```

to allocate memory to both matrix and used :

```
for (int i = 0; i < imgHeight; ++i) {
memcpy(stateMatrix2[i], stateMatrix1[i], imgWidth * sizeof(SDL_Color));
}
```

to perform the copy.
I also verified that the two matrix were'nt linked and there were no problem.

Comment: `stateMatrix1` is not a continuous block of memory. It's made up of many seperate blocks of `malloc` memory and thus cannot be copied with a single `memcpy`.

Comment: `stateMatrix2` is a two-dimensional array, but `stateMatrix1` is an array of pointers, pointing to arrays of `SDL_Color` -> different types.

Comment: @kaylum
oh so the solution would be to loop with ```memcpy(stateMatrix2[i], stateMatrix1[i], imgWidth*sizeof(SDL_Color)```?

Comment: @OlafDietsche
So I have to declare matrix2 in the same way as matrix 1?

Comment: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When copying

```
memcpy(stateMatrix2, stateMatrix1, imgWidth * imgHeight * sizeof(SDL_Color));
```

you will go beyond the end of `stateMatrix1`, which is not `imgWidth * imgHeight * sizeof(SDL_Color)`, but `imgHeight * sizeof(SDL_Color*)`.

---

Copying in a loop from `stateMatrix1` to `stateMatrix2` is one way to solve this

```
for (int i = 0; i < imgHeight; ++i) {
    memcpy(stateMatrix2[i], stateMatrix1[i], imgWidth * sizeof(SDL_Color));
}
```

---

Another would be making both matrices the same type. But when allocating `stateMatrix2` as

```
SDL_Color **stateMatrix2 = (SDL_Color **) malloc(imgHeight * sizeof(SDL_Color*));
```

and later use the same `memcpy` as above, you will still go beyond `stateMatrix1` *and* now also beyond the end of `stateMatrix2`.

---

The correct way to copy (but still wrong for another reason) would be

```
memcpy(stateMatrix2, stateMatrix1, sizeof(*stateMatrix1));
```

This is correct in terms of size, but still wrong, because it copies the *pointers* of `stateMatrix1` to `stateMatrix2`. This has two effects

1. When you initialized `stateMatrix2` with its own pointers, there will be memory leaks.
2. Now both matrices point to the same memory, which means changing one, will change the other too.

Comment: I posted my fix using your answer by editing my question, if you have some extra comment about it tell me. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Your error is explained in comments. You could fix it by allocating a contiguous block of memory for your matrix instead of many blocks as you did. This way of doing is even simpler, for allocation, deallocation and copy (since you can then use a single call to memcpy) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct SDL_Color {
    unsigned char rgba[4];
};

int main() {
    int ch, pix;
    int imgWidth = 100;
    int imgHeight = 100;
    struct SDL_Color (*stateMatrix1)[imgWidth][imgHeight] = malloc(sizeof(*stateMatrix1));
    if (*stateMatrix1 == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory\n");
    } else {
        free(*stateMatrix1);
        printf("Success\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You just need to take care of dereferencing the pointer to the matrix each time you use it.

Comment: The thing is I have to pass those 2D array in a function as parameters. In order to achieve it I have to build my stateMatrix as pointer of pointer right?

Comment: Unless `imgWidth` and `imgHeight` are constant literals, the it would be best to allocated pointers and storage for each row instead of using a VLA (as support for VLAs is optional beginning with C11). If you have the option of simulating a 2D array using a single block -- that is always preferred for the single-allocate/single-free simplicity. If the SDL functions expect a pointer-to-pointer, then that is what you are stuck with. Here `(*stateMatrix1)[imgWidth][imgHeight]` is a pointer-to-2D-VLA.